# Concept of a database driven program in VB.NET

Tags: database, vb.net

I have been developing programs in VB.NET for a few years and am familiar with it. The area where I do not have a lot of exposure is databases.

I am writing a program (for my personal use) called movie manager. It will store information on movies I have. I have selected Sql Server Compact Edition database. Assume I have a database with two tables namely Info and Cast. Info table has a few columns such as movie_name, release_date and so on. Cast table has few cols such as first_name,last_name etc.

Right now I have created a DataSet which reads all the info of tables from database (opens connection, fills tables info, closes connection). This way in a global variable I have a snapshot of database.

My queries :

1. Once I have data with me, every time I need to add, edit or delete a record I have to open a connection, fire an sql and close the connection. Right ? Is there a way to do this without using Sql ? Plus is this concept okay.
2. Since I am not using structures so I need to create empty datasets to store temp information. Is this convenient ?
3. If I have to search for a specific thing in dataset table, then do I have to loop thru all items or can I use sql on dataset or is there an alternate ?

Comment: Take a look at [Entity Data Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee382825.aspx)

Comment: @rs. he should probably figure out the basics of what's going on before he tackles entity, I think.

Comment: To answer your questions, you typically hire a guy who is paid at $1000/hr to determine a solution for all of the above, that will consider all the caveats that are specific to your application. There is no right answer for a generic situation. It's much like "I wanna build an aircraft, should I use aluminum? should I have turbines? Do I use leather for passenger seats?"

Answer (score 3):

1)Once I have data with me, every time I need to add, edit or delete a record I have to open a connection, fire an sql and close the connection. Right ? Is there a way to do this without using Sql ? Plus is this concept okay.

***No. To update a database, you have to use the database. Create a stored procedure in the database to handle your functionality and then call it from the code and pass in whatever data needs saved. DO NOT USE INLINE SQL. Paramterized stored procedures are the way to go.***

2) Since I am not using structures so I need to create empty datasets to store temp information. Is this convenient ?

***It depends on what you're doing. I would create an object model to retain my updated data and then I'd pass the properties into the stored procedure when it was time to save my changes.***

3) If I have to search for a specific thing in dataset table, then do I have to loop thru all items or can I use sql on dataset or is there an alternate ?

***You can loop the rows or you can use linq to pull what you need out. Linq is really nice as it's basically .NET coded queries against a collection.***

There are plenty of tutorials/guides out there to show you how to update via stored proc call form your code. There are a ton of linq tutorials as well. Basically, a linq query against your table will look something like:

```
dim result as Generic.List(of String) =
  (from r in table.AsEnumerable()
  select r
  where r["columnName"] = "the value").ToList()
```

This syntax is probably a bit off, but it looks something like that.

### Edit

Your Model:

```
Public Class EmployeeModel
    Public Property Id
    Public Property FirstName
    Public Property Last Name
    Public Property JobCode
    Public Sub EmployeeModel(your params)
        //set properties
    End Sub
End Class
```

Your DAL:

```
Public Shared Class EmployeeDAL
    Public Shared Sub SaveEmployee(ByRef model as EmployeeModel)
       // call your sp_SaveEmployee stored procedure and set the parameters to the model properties
       // @id = EmpoyeeModel.Id
       // @JobCode = Employee.JobCode
       // ...
    End Sub
End Class
```

I use VB every few months, so there are probably some small syntax errors in there. But that's basically all you need to do. The function to save your data is in the DAL, not in the class itself. If you don't want to use a DAL, you can put the save functionality in your class, though. It'll work the same way, it's just not as clearly separated.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.

1) I will create stored procedures to add, edit or delete data in database.
2) This is tricky. You see I did not understand your statement "I would create an object model to retain my updated data...". What I mean is since I am not using structures, then if I want to save temp data in memory then should I use empty datasets as they already contain appropriate tables and columns. Is this okay ?
3) I will try to use LINQ/Loop to get data from dataset.

Comment: @Greatchap I would create a class (object model is a class that represents your data) to retain that data. It won't take much work, honestly. It'll most likely be a simple class with properties representing the data you need. However, if you want to retain something in a table in Session, you can do that as well. I just don't think it's the best way. You could also use a collection of `KeyValuePairs` or a `Dictionary` as well.

Comment: In an application you create a structure and depends on usage you create an array of that structure and store values in it. Those values can be used on temporary basis and when you think you need to write it, you write them to a file or db. The same way I thought rather than creating a structure which would contain the same fields of the database tables, I could use a temp dataset as it would have all table fields and store values in it. If I think I need to write them then I can send that variable to a function/sub which would add them to database. I hope this is okay.

Comment: @Greatchap It's your program, the decision is yours, man. I made a recommendation and you can either use it or not. If you want to use a table/dataset - do it. Design decisions are yours to make. I can only make a recommendation. If my answer helped you, up-vote and accept it, please.

Comment: Man I didn't mean to offend you. I accept what you said. The only point that I wanted to discuss was the second one. I know it my program and if I didn't want to check my thoughts I wouldn't have posted in the first place. In coding there is no hardcoded rule to do things. All I wanted to know was if my way of doing was okay or not. Mean would you think its a viable alternate or I am going the wrong way?

Comment: @Greatchap I'm not offended at all. I'm simply saying I gave you a way that I feel is a better way to go, but you seem intent on doing it a different way. You CAN do it your way. You can make any collection/container work for you with enough effort. I just don't think it's the best way to go about it. Either way, best of luck in whichever route you decide to take.

Comment: Let me go by your way. In that I need to create a class, then either a property or a structure in a class that will hold all data. Then function in that class to manage (add/update) that data. Is that correct ? My question is in that case don't I have to create a replica of database table fields and have methods to move them from array to datasets for saving and all. I was wondering using a dataset (empty) I get structure ready made and can have functions to read/write. If I am making a mistake here please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @Greatchap Edited my question to provide a simple example. I didn't put all of the db code in there as you should know how to do that already. If not, there are a ton of examples already on the web.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Assuming only one database can be open at a time I have two questions which I think should clear a few things. (Method (1)) I create a class, create properties which can be used to store/get values. Function/Sub to read, save or perform something on the data. Right ? (Method (2)) I hold all data in a main dataset which is global. I use temp datasets to store temp data. I write global sub/functions to load, save or manage data. The first method requires more coding, creating properties which should match table fields and sub/func. In 2nd if I use empty dataset..

Comment: (continued from above) If I use empty dataset I get table and fields automatically. I can create subs which can read 1 or all record of temp data and add or update them to main dataset as ordered. I was wondering in such a case is it still better to go by the class method or what I mentioned? Your help is educating me.

Comment: @Greatchap I'm happy to help, but I've already told you that I feel my solution is a cleaner and better solution. It's also an extendable solution. If you want to use your solution, *you can* and you can make it work just fine. But you shouldn't get hung up on coding less. You should focus on doing what's best. If this is all you ever want your solution to do, do it your way. If you ever want to extend it to do more, I would recommend my solution. This is the last I'm going to comment as I feel I'm just repeating myself. I hope I helped. Decide what you want to do and move forward with it.

Comment: I don't think SQL CE has stored procedures.  Parameterized queries are ok to use.

Comment: @LarsTech I didn't know that. Good info.

Comment: @Greatchap see LarsTech's comment.

Answer (score 2):

On your Questions.

number 1: You have to connect to database in order to store and retrieve data. There are lots of ways on how to deal with it and one way of it is to use app.config or you may simply create a function that calls the connection every time you need it.

number 2: Since you are dealing with dataset here are some tips you might want to look at [DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8bw9ksd6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

number 3: You can also try using Data Adapter and Data Table. I am not sure what you meant by your question number 3.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I have problem with the way you are using your database and the ram of your computer.
 Problem1: since you already have a database for holding the movies information why are you again holding the same information in memory?, creating an extra overhead. if your answer is for performance or i have cheap memory then why don't you use xml or flatfile instead? Database is not needed with this senario.

Problem2: You are like a soldier who dosent know about the weapon he use? right? because you are asking silly questions your first question about opening connection.. the answer is yes you have to open the connection every time save/read the data and close it **as soon as possible.**
 your second question about convinent the answer is no. instead create class with all field as property and some method for initialization,saving,deleting. this way you have to write less code. nad suppose you have a movie names xyz there can be another movie xyz how will you distinguish it? if you have whole information b4 you you can do it via release date ,casts etc, but still it will be hard, so create a primary key for both your table

and finally your 3rd question , it will be easier to use use sql queries than looping thru the dataset(get rid of the dataset as soon as possible) 
wish yu good luck on the road to **rdbms**

Comment: Thanks for your reply but there is confusion that why you think I am asking silly questions.(1) my db has 5 tables (2) I know about primary keys and my tables have them (3) in example I mentioned bare min to just get going. (4) flat file isn't suitable here as tables have movies info with each movie having info on actors and each movie connecting to image table and so on. I need to use a db. (5) I will have a common function for saving and updating but I just wanted to confirm that I need to open/close connection in each case. (6) Without loading dataset in memory how can I search, read info ?